# How to use doublebuffer in listview in windowsmobile

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-mobile, mfc

does any one please tell me how to use double-buffer in windows-mobile listview

Thanks
Grabi8

Answer (score 2):

There is no double-buffering of standard windows controls.  What you probably want to do is turn off painting while adding items, then turn it back on.

SendMessage(hwndList, WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0);

(fill the list)

SendMessage(hwndList, WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE, 0);

Comment: Or if you are using C# use ListView.BeginUpdate and ListView.EndUpdate, detailed in this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ListView on Windows Mobile has a feature called Extended Styles. You can enable the Double Buffering extended style.

Here's an article describing how to do this

http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2008/10/listview-extended-styles-in-netcf.html

Comment: Thanks i had read ur blog,its very nice.. Thanks for great post